# is_numeric é seguro para fazer SELECT?

Tags: php, sql, segurança

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com PDO, e uso normalmente o `bindValue()` para executar os `SELECT`'s, mas estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que recebe uma variável que contém números e vírgula, que posteriormente serão explodidos.

O que queria saber é: Dessa forma é segura para evitar ataques, senão, como seriam efetuados esses ataques?

```
$categories = '10,12,22,123,120'; # ESSES SÃO OS ID'S DAS CATEGORIAS DESEJADAS
$category = explode(',', $categories);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($category); $i++) {
    if (is_numeric($category[$i]) {
        $this->condition .= "categoryName = '{$category[$i]}'";
        if ($i < count($category) - 1) {
            $this->condition .= ' AND ';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O que não faz sentido é usar uma única coluna para armazenar vários valores. O `is_numeric` permite números gigantes, maiores do que o máximo do uint64, o que pode ser um problema. Além disso, ele permite float.

Comment: Na verdade é uma tabela auxiliar para fazer um SELECT de muitos para muitos, o is_numeric serve para autenticar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como é somente número, creio que não seja possível fazer ataque com `SQL Injection`, mas para tirar qualquer dúvida você pode fazer esse processo utilizando o `bindValue()`. Basta utilizar parâmetros nomeados:

```
$categories = '10,12,22,123,120';
$category = explode(',', $categories);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($category); $i++) {
    if (is_numeric($category[$i]) {
        $this->condition .= "categoryName = :category{$i}";
        if ($i < count($category) - 1) {
            $this->condition .= ' AND ';
        }
    }
}
$query = $sua_conexao_pdo->prepare($variavel_com_select." ".$this->condition);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($category); $i++) {
    if (is_numeric($category[$i]) {
        $query->bindValue(":category{$i}", $category[$i], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
}
$query->execute();
```